# Embedded google maps into a circle div in google chrome

Tags: html, google-maps, google-chrome, firefox, geometry

I have problem with google maps.

As you can see on this link: http://fenixreklama.cz/kontakt.html

In Firefox is no problem, embedded map is in black circle, but in Google Chrome the map is rectangle above black circle.

How can this be solved?

Comment: Can you please post the code here or better - in a jsfiddle? (jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Sorry, here is jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/xixaom/qtL4t0j2/1/

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to put iframe with map into div with radius border and set overflow to hidden, of course.